# Clean way to create user and issue jwt token?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, backend

Currently i have an ***AuthenticationController*** which listens on post ***registration***.
This registration method, stores the user and create a jwt token.

```cs
    [HttpPost("registration")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([FromBody] RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           return BadRequest(new { code = "ModelNotValid", description = "Model is not valid." });
       
       if (_userService.UserNameTaken(model.UserName))
           return BadRequest(new { code = "UserNameTaken", description = $"The User Name 
                {model.UserName} is taken." });
       
       var identityResult = await _userService.CreateUserAsync(model);
       
       if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
           return BadRequest(identityResult.Errors);
       
       var user = _userService.GetUserByUserName(model.UserName);
       int validityDurationInHours = 3;
       string token = _jwtService.GenerateJwtToken(user, await _userService.GetUserRolesAsync(user), 
           validityDurationInHours);
        
        return Ok(new { code = "RegistrationSuccess", auth_token = token });
    }
```

But now i would like to refactor the code, so there would be a ***UsersController*** which saves the user and i am not sure if i should generate the jwt token in the same method as it is done now.

So i what i see as a way is when the user registers on client side it sends the data to the backend, if it was correct than the client will be notifed, which than redirects user to the login page. But i feel unnecesarry the redirection, the user data was correct so it should get the jwt token straigth away.
But i am unsure that the issueing the token should be done by the userscontroller default post method, which saves the user.

The other way i see is when the user is saved the backend notifies the client and than the client create a new request to the backend to issue the token. But then the request feels unnecessary.

Comment: `so there would be a UsersController which saves the user and i am not sure if i should generate the jwt token in the same method as it is done now.`Can you explain more about this?

Comment: Would you consider a controller creating entity in the database needs to issue jwt token aswell? I would like to separate the two.

Comment: Why don't you use the build-in SignInManager?

Comment: Because this is a backend for an SPA. (Not real backend, just learning)

Comment: I think this maybe better suited for CodeReview -- there is nothing wrong with your code and you don't seem to have a problem you are trying to fix. I think keeping them in the same method is fine. Otherwise you're going to have a method that calls another method which is redundant.

Comment: If there is an entity controller, do you think it is a good idea that this controller isuess the jwt token also?